# While loop is not breaking even after the condition is satisfied

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've provided the code below.

What is want to do is run the first input box where it will check the condition if true it will go for next input(), but if not it will run the code again. The problem is first input() is running fine, but second one is not getting out of the loop where I'm checking if the input is integer or not

```
class AC ():
    
     
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.owner=input("Enter The Name: ")
        
        while True:
            if self.owner.isalpha():
                self.balance=(input("Enter The Amount: "))
                def lol():
                    while True:
                        if self.balance.isdigit():
                             break
                        else:
                            print("Enter The Amount: ") 
                            lol()
                            break
                        
            
            else:
                
                AC()
                break
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What input does the code fail for?

Comment: For self.balance .  Where I want to see if the value entered is integer or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `lol()` function is never being called as Tim said
2. `input()` function return string value you can change str to float
3. try this:

`

```
def __init__(self):
    self.owner = input("Enter The Name: ")


    while True:
        if self.owner.isalpha():
            self.balance = input("Enter The Amount: ")
            def lol():
                while True:
                    try:
                        self.balance = float(self.balance)
                    except ValueError:
                        break
            if self.balance.isdigit():
                break
            else:
                lol()
        else:
            AC()
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `lol()` function is never being called for, so it will stay in the first while-loop indefinitely.

Comment: How can I call it ?

Comment: Just put `lol()` after `self.balance=(input("Enter The Amount: "))`
Also, you can remove these 2 lines: `print("Enter The Amount: ")`  & `lol()` from the else-statement.